# C# Получение данных из mssql по полю datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, ado.net

Всем привет! Ситуация следующая.

1. По данным из формы генерируется запрос к бд oracle.
2. Посредством ado.net грузятся данные в дататэйбл из oracle.
3. После этого нужно выгрузить в другую datatable ещё одну таблицу из бд MSSQL на основании поля id, загруженного в п.2. То есть по сути заджойнить таблицу в datatable и таблицу в бд mssql.

Mssql и oracle доступны только для чтения.
Циклом отправлять запросы по каждой записи загруженной в datatable не вариант, т.к.в ней может быть более 400 тыс записей и это затягивается на несколько дней.

Посоветуйте как можно реализовать загрузку в datatable описанную в п.3 на c# ?

Comment: То ли я чего не понимаю, то ли вы запросами пользоваться не умеете, по сути, получили данные, взяли id-шник запросили по нему данные, если надо множество id использовать, то тут использовать or `id=1 or id=2 or ...`

Comment: Сформировать блок(и) из набора id-ов (`WHERE id IN (...)`, но не выходя за допустимый предел размера текста запроса) и запрашивать у MS SQL информацию сразу по всему блоку.

Comment: Альтернативно - загрузить полученные id во временную таблицу на MS SQL, и делать выборку с её использованием.

Comment: Загрузить нельзя в mssql, т.к. доступ только на чтение. Формировать через or это будет нечто, т.к. более 400 тыс записей.

Comment: Хотелось бы что-то вроде linq между datatable  и sql , но как это реализовать совсем не нашел

Comment: _что-то вроде linq_ - ну так стандартный linq: метод `Contains`, его использование описано везде и всюду. В sql он раскрывается в `in`.

Comment: _Загрузить нельзя_ - а я говорю можно. Потому что _затягивается на несколько дней_ - объясняете это руководству и вам дают право на запись (что именно и как будет разрешено - дело админа СУБД).

Comment: А вообще, Sql Server и Oracle поддерживают возможность объединения. То есть вполне можно сделать `join` таблиц разных СУБД. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3992573/5045688)